# How to convert String to date type using fromLocaleString() function?

Tags: qt, qml, invalid-argument

I need to convert the time chosen on two tumblers to `date` QML type. I want the resulting `date` to be returned via a function `alarm_time()`.

I am using the `Date.fromLocaleString(locale, dateTimeString, format)` function for conversion. According to the [Qt Documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-date.html#fromLocaleString-method) the `locale` argument does not have to be specified.

Here is the simplified code:

```
Frame {

    function format_number(number) {
        return number < 10 && number >= 0 ? "0" + number : number.toString()
    }

    function alarm_time() {
        return Date.fromLocaleString(
            format_number(hours_tumbler.currentIndex) + ":" + format_number(minutes_tumbler.currentIndex), "hh:mm")
    }

    RowLayout {

        Tumbler {
            id: hours_tumbler
            model: 24
        }

        Tumbler {
            id: minutes_tumbler
            model: 60
        }

    }
}
```

Now, when invoking the function, I get the following error:

`Error: Locale: Date.fromLocaleString(): Invalid arguments`

The error is self explanatory...

Later I tried specifying the `locale` argument according to the instructions in [Qt Documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-date.html#fromLocaleString-method). The code looks like this now:

```
Frame {

    function format_number(number) {
        return number < 10 && number >= 0 ? "0" + number : number.toString()
    }

    property var locale: Qt.locale() // Here is something new...

    function alarm_time() {
        return Date.fromLocaleString(locale, // ...and here.
            format_number(hours_tumbler.currentIndex) + ":" + format_number(minutes_tumbler.currentIndex), "hh:mm")
    }

    RowLayout {

        Tumbler {
            id: hours_tumbler
            model: 24
        }

        Tumbler {
            id: minutes_tumbler
            model: 60
        }

    }
}
```

Now the error message is different:

`Cannot override FINAL property`

Now I'm stuck and I can't really come up with a solution to this problem. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overriding `Frame`'s existing `locale` property (It comes from `Control`). Simply come up with a different name for it:

```
property var myLocale: Qt.locale()
```

Comment: Thank You! Apparently late night coding and overtrusting the qt docs was not the best tactic as I haven't seen that little detail.